# TomEE Embedded stops as systemctl service

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, apache-tomee, systemctl

i have some confusing behavior in one of our projets. We build a maven project which we stage by git. In our project we use tomee-embedded (v. 8.0.0) to start and run our application with a few commands on diffrent environments. That works pretty wells that far.

Acutally we wanted to deploy it on a server, so we did `git clone ...` and `mvn clean install tomee-embedded:run`and it worked pretty well.

To get some testing experience we wanted to keep the application running as service so we created a systemd service which contains:

```
[Unit]
Description=[… our description …]
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart = /bin/bash -c '/usr/share/maven/bin/mvn clean install tomee-embedded:run -f [path/to/our/application]
Restart=on-failure

User=root ## necessary to run on port 80.
WorkingDirectory=[onceagain/path/to/our/application]

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This was also so far so good, when we start our service it runs the maven stuff, builds our application and starts up our tomcat, but then it stops immediately with log:

```
[INFO] TomEE embedded started on localhost:8080
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 27.717 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-03T10:28:16+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 56M/204M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
[INFO] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
[INFO] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]
[INFO] Stopping service [Tomcat]Dez 03 10:28:17 h2790697.stratoserver.net rhorun.sh[31795]: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:267)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal(StandardService.java:473)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stopInternal(StandardServer.java:994)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.stop(Tomcat.java:466)
at org.apache.tomee.embedded.Container.stop(Container.java:846)
at org.apache.openejb.maven.plugins.TomEEEmbeddedMojo$2.run(TomEEEmbeddedMojo.java:425)
Dez 03 10:28:17 h2790697.stratoserver.net rhorun.sh[31795]: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/core/ContainerBase$StopChild
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:976)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
... 7 more
Dez 03 10:28:17 h2790697.stratoserver.net rhorun.sh[31795]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
... 9 more
```

So it looks as if maven builds correctly and our tomcat starts properly but immediately after the start of our tomcat is completed, the procedure is finished and the tomcat stops again. A behaviour we do not have if we run `sudo mvn clean install tomee-embedded:run`.

Is there may someone who could help us?

Comment: One small hint in advance: we tried also to use the `ExecStart` without /bin/bash and use the complete path to mvn. It had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

So due to some project pressure we build up a quick & dirty solution which works currently:
We moved our maven command to `screen` and have it running in background. The executing script ist handeled `@reboot`as cronjob for having a running server also when a machine-reboot was necessary.